# does kernel or filter update through backpropagation , is require fully connected layers?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

does CNN itself without FC has the ability to make backpropagation to update its filters, after comparing them with the output and calculating the loss, and then pass them through the FCC?

Comment: What is FCC? Fully Connected ... ?

Comment: yes, sorry, i meant FC

Comment: CNNs work with backpropagation. For backpropagation to work, you don't have to have fully connected layers.

Comment: what if there is an Fc at the end? do we need to go through it for each epoch or batch in order to update filters or just the final output of the features map will pass through FC?